# How can I generate wallet files for multibit or armory?

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat, multibit, armory

I'm considering working on a bitcoin project that will need to generate wallet files.  I'm not looking to create receipt addresses that a customer can send funds to for an existing wallet.  Instead, I need to generate numerous wallet files, each with preferably only 1 payment address, that can be distributed across multiple locations.

Can this easily be done from a daemon command or with an existing API?  If there is an API for this, any language is fine, though I would prefer Python.

Comment: Related: [pywallet](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet)

Comment: Thanks Nick ODell.  Post an answer and I'll give you a +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MultiBit you could use the command line utility called WalletTool that Mike Hearn wrote. You can use it to create bitcoinj wallets (which is what MultiBit uses). 
There is a description of it here:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=43616.msg1451177#msg1451177

You could wrap calls to it in your favourite scripting tool fairly easily I imagine.

Comment: And what about armory?? Also I can't even find WalletTool... link?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this utility called [pywallet](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet/blob/master/pywallet.py). You don't need to run pywallet from the command line though - just put it in the same directory, do `import pywallet`, and you can use any of the functions in there. You should try running it from the command line first though, because it'll show you any missing dependencies.

Functions you might find interesting:

- [`create_new_wallet`](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet/blob/master/pywallet.py#L1087)
- [`KEY.generate`](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet/blob/master/pywallet.py#L673)
- [`update_wallet`](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet/blob/master/pywallet.py#L1013)